# Determine location using Microsoft Location Service API in Windowsphone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

I submit my app on windows-phone7 store, Microsoft need following requirement to certify the app.
The following requirements apply to applications that receive the location of a user's mobile device:
2.7.1 Your application must determine location using Microsoft Location Service API.
2.7.2 The privacy policy of your application must inform users about how location data from the Location Service API is used and disclosed and the controls that users have over the use and sharing
of location data. This can be hosted within or directly linked from the application.
 Please help me what i want to mentioned or implement to certify the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to get the location.

```
            private static GeoCoordinateWatcher Watcher;            

            private void StartGeoWatcher()
            {

                if (Watcher == null)
                {
                    Watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                    Watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(OnPositionChanged);
                    Watcher.TryStart(false, System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                }

            }

            private void OnPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
            {

                    latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
                    longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;


            }
```

Comment: Thank you, But in the following link also i got ideas instead of using "http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common" geocode. Needs to use system.device.location geocodeservice API.

Comment: GeoCoordinateWatcher already implements Microsoft Location Service API. Also, to pass certification you need to add some text that describes why you need user location and how you will use it. And don't forget to add switch of turn off Location Service in your app.

Comment: That is interesting, I have an app that uses GeoCoordinateWatcher and I didnt have to do anything that you noted, but it does say that is needed in the policy documentation.