# How can I determine the source of location - GPS or network in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, location

So, is it possible to determine whether location is determined using GPS or Network?

Comment: Does this questions answer help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707840/determine-location-using-microsoft-location-service-api-in-windowsphone7

Answer (score 2):

When `GPS` is locked, you receive `VerticalAccuracy` property with `GeoCoordinate` object.

When location is determined by `Cellular` or `WiFi` you always receive `NaN` in `VerticalAccuracy`